# Print unmatched patterns in grep in TCSH shell

Tags: grep

I have a list of patterns which i want to search in a file and find out which patterns are not matching. How to make  grep print some error message or the unmatched pattern to know that pattern doesnt exist?

> grep "Macro ABC" base.txt 
>   This doesn't return anything as the pattern doesn't exist in base.txt.

Answer (score 2):

You could use bash for this. If you have all your patterns in a file, you could read that file and check if the pattern is matched in your base file:

```
FILENAME=patterns.txt
while read -r pattern
do
    if ! grep "$pattern" base.txt; then
        echo "This doesn't return anything as $pattern doesn't exist in base.txt"
    fi
done < "$FILENAME"
```